# Регулярное выражение php для редложений

Tags: php

Что нужно добавить к регулярке "/^[а-яёa-z0-9]+$i/" что бы она также пропускала пробелы и следующие спецсимволы: '"!?.,-+/
?

Comment: Пропускала? -  /[а-яёa-z0-9 \!\?\.\,\-\+\/]+$/

Comment: А кавычки, апострофы, точку с запятой и двоеточие разве не надо добавить? В любом случае - принцип тот же, что предложил Константин.